# Merging JSON files but only specific keys

Tags: python, json

A `for` loop of API calls returns a JSON object for each call and appends it to a master JSON file.

However, the individual JSON files that each call returns are not identical: some files have keys others don't or in different order, so my merged JSON file doesn't look right, especially when converted to CSV.

As I only need a few keys(columns):

1. Is there a way to only append specific keys by name?
2. Alternatively, is there a way to skip the JSON conversion and append the specific keys to CSV?

Here's my code so far:

```py
json_arr = []
for rule in rules:
    tweets = collect_results(rule,
                             max_results=100,
                             result_stream_args=premium_search_args)
    json_arr.append(tweets)
    with open(filename1, 'a') as f_obj:
        json.dump(tweets, f_obj)`
```

`collect_results()` is a function of the API and `rules` is a list containing the parameters for each call (=Tweets from specific time windows).

Comment: What type of data structure is `tweets`, when you get it? Is it a string, or a dict? If the latter, you can index into it and get whatever keys you want and do whatever you want *with* them. IF the former, but it's shaped like JSON, you can do `json.loads()` to get it into a dict.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. `tweets` is a string shaped like a JSON file. I would like to be able to tell Python to only grab specific key-value pairs (retrieved by key name) from each `tweets` object and append those to the final JSON file. I can't use key index numbers because the different `tweets` files don't have all the same keys in the same order.